# parsing, time scheduling ,table view reload data

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, parsing

I have three classes, I am simply display my Facebook friends in tableView. And i successfully get my all friend name in an friendArray. I have to display friends name in FriendList class.

1)RootViewController class

2)FriendList class

3)Facebook interaction class

**My problem is :**

My FriendList class load before fetching(parsing) complete. and in my Array **friendArray count is 0.(because (fetching)parsing not complete)**. In my console array count is 150.

```
friendListObject.friendArray = parsedArray; // where get data

-(void)butoonClicked               
{
    FBFeedPost *post = [[FBFeedPost alloc]initWithFriendList:self.imageView.image];
    [post publishPostWithDelegate:self];
    FriendList *friendList=[[FriendList alloc]initWithNibName:@"FriendList" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:friendList  animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass the array of friends to the class FriendList when you complete parsing of the facebook data. This you can do by calling a function in FriendList . You can fill friendListObject.friendArray using this passed array and call `[tableview reloadData];`

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` has a method called `reloadData` to refresh itself and all the datasource methods of it.

Simply call `[yourTable reloadData]` when the parser finishes parsing.